# TimerTask, Geolocation and Looper

Tags: android, geolocation, timertask, looper

I need to perform the follow logic in my application:
Every minute, I want to be able to listen to GPS location for 20 seconds to get a GEO-location fix.

This obviously needs to run a different thread than the UI thread.

I am however having some problems with using looper and timertask in conjuction...

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) :

**Android doc :**

> A Service is an application component representing either an application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not interacting with the user or to supply functionality for other applications to use.

So the Service start the [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) using [requestLocationUpdates()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) and implements [LocationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html).

Then you have (at least) two solutions (depending on what you want to do) :

- dispatch the event to the Activity that need to use the Location ( with a Broadcast for example )
- the Activity has an access to the service and uses a getter to get the latest location.